# Is it weird to end a message with "mit freundlichen grüßen" after already speaking in English (with a German person)

Tags: etiquette

I'm a native English speaker, who is attempting to learn German.  I've been having an email conversation with a German customer who wrote to me in English.  I would like to make some small, friendly gesture, like maybe ending an otherwise English-language email with "mit freundlichen grüßen".  Would a typical German person find that weird/offensive?  (Or maybe, hopefully, a nice gesture?)

Comment: Native german myself I would consider that as nice gesture. I think that's how most maybe even all would see it. Maybe, just maybe there're people who think it's weird or are irritated and think you're german, but I'm sure that no one would feel offended by it. I think you can go for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I consider myself a typical German person, and as such I find adding some kind words in the mother tongue of the recipient a nice and friendly move. I do this myself almost always in my correspondence with project partners in other countries. Similarly, my project partners do this vice versa.

Viele Grüße!

Christian

---

PS: Aber es wäre noch besser, dabei auch auf die richtige Schreibung zu achten: *Mit freundlichen Grüßen* - achte auf die Großbuchstaben!

Comment: Sorry to be a bit picky, but IMHO MfG is a very formal ending perhaps not always suited as a friendly gesture. However German lacks an ending which is in between formal seen, so I have no good alternative.

Comment: @thomas I would categorize "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" as a polite, but otherwise empty pleasantry. It is a phrase you have learned to use as an ending in letters or e-mails, but I would never expect anyone writing a letter to me and finalizing it with "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" to express any specific mood or meaning.

Comment: "I consider myself a typical German person" - sorry, but what should that be? There is no such thing as a typical German person.

Comment: The *PS* should be in English as well so that the asker can understand it without auxiliary devices. I consider the PS very important because I personally as the receiver would prefer a correct English closing over an orthographically poor German closing.